# custom overlay on a google map

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have my marker html currently sitting on top of a google map using css. Problem is that it's not connected to the map.. so when you pan the map the marker does not move with it. What part of the v3 api could help with this?

```
My marker:
<div class="placemarker-290">
 <span class="avatar-47">
  <a href="/"><img src="/images/" alt="Medium"></a>
 </span>
 <h3><a href="#">Name</a></h3>
 <p>Address</p>
 <p>Location</p>
 <span class="footer"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Beyond modifying the base [marker](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#Marker) object itself, Google wrote a couple [libraries](http://code.google.com/p/google-maps-utility-library-v3/wiki/Libraries) that allow for greater marker customization, i.e. Marker With Label, StyledMarker and RichMarker (this may be the most helpful).

Comment: Thanks. The marker with label worked for me. http://blog.mridey.com/2009/09/label-overlay-example-for-google-maps.html